# Use ast to get all function calls in a function

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to list all function call in a function using ast. But having trouble understanding how it is suppose to be used. I have been able to get this far.

```
set := token.NewFileSet()
packs, err := parser.ParseFile(set, serviceFile, nil, 0)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Failed to parse package:", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

funcs := []*ast.FuncDecl{}
for _, d := range packs.Decls {
    if fn, isFn := d.(*ast.FuncDecl); isFn {
        funcs = append(funcs, fn)
    }
}
```

I have inspected funcs. I get to `funcs[n1].Body.List[n2]`.
But after this i don't understand how i'm suppose to read the underlaying `data.X.Fun.data.Sel.name` (got it from evaluation in gogland) to get name of the function being called.

Comment: I find it's helpful to [print](https://godoc.org/go/ast#Print) example trees when trying to understand how to use the go/ast package. If you need to distinguish function calls from conversions, it may easier to use go/types.

Comment: write the desired func to inspect, write code similar to https://golang.org/pkg/go/ast/#Print, load and inspect your code (pass directly the func.Body node). +/- https://gist.github.com/mh-cbon/3ed5d9c39e9635cfed0f896000098133. This will help a lot working with ast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so what i found is that you have to a lot of casting to actually extract the data.

Here is an example on how to do extract the func call in a func.

```
for _, function := range funcs {
    extractFuncCallInFunc(function.Body.List)
}

func extractFuncCallInFunc(stmts []ast.Stmt) {
    for _, stmt := range funcs {
        if exprStmt, ok := stmt.(*ast.ExprStmt); ok {
            if call, ok := exprStmt.X.(*ast.CallExpr); ok {
                if fun, ok := call.Fun.(*ast.SelectorExpr); ok {
                    funcName := fun.Sel.Name
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also found this with kind of help with finding out what you need to cast it to.
http://goast.yuroyoro.net/

Comment: This will not catch all situations. Consider the following expression: `b := a.c()`. This would produce a AssignStmt -> [Rhs member of AssignStmt] -> CallExpr -> SelectorExpr. Your extractFuncCallInFunc() would miss this case.

Comment: Another example would be `b := a.c(d.e)`, you'd miss the `d.e` part as well. I don't think there exists an easy  way to find all SelectorExpr in a FuncDelc.Body...

Answer (score 2):

you can use ast.Inspect for that and use a switch on the type of the node.

```
for _, fun := range funcs {
    ast.Inspect(fun, func(node ast.Node) bool {
        switch n := node.(type) {
            case *ast.CallExpr:
                fmt.Println(n) // prints every func call expression
        }
        return true
    })
}
```